# Convergence of $(f(x))^2$ if $f(x)$ is positive and continuous and converges

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I am trying to show that if $f$ is a positive continuous function on $[1, \infty )$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, then if $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ converges  $\int_{1}^{\infty} (f(x))^2 dx$ converges as well.
My first inclination is that this is false, but I am having trouble finding counter examples. This is a first year calculus course, so please keep answers to that level.

Comment: If $f$ is positive and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, then eventually $0<f(x)<1$ and therefore $0<f(x)^2<f(x)$.

Comment: @RobertZ nitpick: you only need $f(x)<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lim_{x\to \infty}{f(x)}=0$, there is an $X$ past which $f(x)<1$, so that $f^2(x)<f(x)$. This should settle your question.

Answer (score 1):

As , there is some $M$ after this $f(x)<1 $ that means for all $x\ge M $ ,

Then $f^{2}(x) < f(x) $ for all $x\ge M $ ,
Now as, $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is convergent $\implies $  $\int_{1}^{\infty}(f(x))^{2}dx$ is so, ( by, comparison test)

Comment: The Integral Test requires $f$ to be (weakly) decreasing, so this doesn't work in general.  But the reason why Abel's Test works is the same reason why the OP's question works.

Comment: @Toby Bartels  but, Abel's test need still , $f$ as monotonic. Abel's test also not applicable . Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Right, it's still true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(f(n))^2$ is convergent as soon as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ is convergent (for positive $f$), but Abel's Test isn't the reason, I didn't catch that.